# Periodic modular piecewise function

Tags: modular-arithmetic, periodic-functions

For every positive integer $n$, let $\text{mod}_5 (n)$ be the remainder obtained when $n$ is divided by 5. Define a function $f: \{0,1,2,3,\dots\} \times \{0,1,2,3,4\} \to \{0,1,2,3,4\}$ recursively as follows:

$$f(i,j) = \begin{cases}\text{mod}_5 (j+1) & \text{ if } i = 0 \text{ and } 0 \le j \le 4 \text{,}\\
f(i-1,1) & \text{ if } i \ge 1 \text{ and } j = 0 \text{, and} \\
f(i-1, f(i,j-1)) & \text{ if } i \ge 1 \text{ and } 1 \le j \le 4.
\end{cases}$$

What is $f(2015,2)$?

I have seen methods for this question but they seem to be making tables to solve it and are very time consuming. What is the least time consuming way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that’s needed is a very small table that can be filled in quite rapidly:

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}
&0&1&2&3&4\\ \hline
0&1&2&3&4&0\\
1&2&3&4&0&1\\
2&3&0&2&4&1\\
3&0&3&4&1&0\\
4&3&1&3&1&3\\
5&1&1&1&1&1
\end{array}$$

And the definition now ensures that $f(i,j)=1$ for all $i\ge 5$ and $j\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}$.

Comment: Just curious, how did you fill in the elements all like that so fast?

Comment: @user19405892: I just followed the definition. The first part of it gives me the top row, and the rest tells me how to work down one row at a time. If I have a row $a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$, I calculate the next row – call it $b_0,b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4$ – from left to right. The second clause of the definition tells me that $b_0=a_1$. Then $b_1$ is $a_{b_0}$, $b_2=a_{b_1}$, $b_3=a_{b_2}$, and $b_4=a_{b_3}$.